# Image represented by text - what is it called?

Tags: css, image, text, png

I've seen in some sample code and other places what appears to be just a bunch of random text, but is rendered as an image.

For example:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABEAAAAQCAYAAADwMZRfAAAEJGlDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAOBGFVd9v21QUPolvUqQWPyBYR4eKxa9VU1u5GxqtxgZJk6XtShal6dgqJOQ6N4mpGwfb6baqT3uBNwb8AUDZAw9IPCENBmJ72fbAtElThyqqSUh76MQPISbtBVXhu3ZiJ1PEXPX6yznfOec7517bRD1fabWaGVWIlquunc8klZOnFpSeTYrSs9RLA9Sr6U4tkcvNEi7BFffO6+EdigjL7ZHu/k72I796i9zRiSJPwG4VHX0Z+AxRzNRrtksUvwf7+Gm3BtzzHPDTNgQCqwKXfZwSeNHHJz1OIT8JjtAq6xWtCLwGPLzYZi+3YV8DGMiT4VVuG7oiZpGzrZJhcs/hL49xtzH/Dy6bdfTsXYNY+5yluWO4D4neK/ZUvok/17X0HPBLsF+vuUlhfwX4j/rSfAJ4H1H0qZJ9dN7nR19frRTeBt4Fe9FwpwtN+2p1MXscGLHR9SXrmMgjONd1ZxKzpBeA71b4tNhj6JGoyFNp4GHgwUp9qplfmnFW5oTdy7NamcwCI49kv6fN5IAHgD+0rbyoBc3SOjczohbyS1drbq6pQdqumllRC/0ymTtej8gpbbuVwpQfyw66dqEZyxZKxtHpJn+tZnpnEdrYBbueF9qQn93S7HQGGHnYP7w6L+YGHNtd1FJitqPAR+hERCNOFi1i1alKO6RQnjKUxL1GNjwlMsiEhcPLYTEiT9ISbN15OY/jx4SMshe9LaJRpTvHr3C/ybFYP1PZAfwfYrPsMBtnE6SwN9ib7AhLwTrBDgUKcm06FSrTfSj187xPdVQWOk5Q8vxAfSiIUc7Z7xr6zY/+hpqwSyv0I0/QMTRb7RMgBxNodTfSPqdraz/sDjzKBrv4zu2+a2t0/HHzjd2Lbcc2sG7GtsL42K+xLfxtUgI7YHqKlqHK8HbCCXgjHT1cAdMlDetv4FnQ2lLasaOl6vmB0CMmwT/IPszSueHQqv6i/qluqF+oF9TfO2qEGTumJH0qfSv9KH0nfS/9TIp0Wboi/SRdlb6RLgU5u++9nyXYe69fYRPdil1o1WufNSdTTsp75BfllPy8/LI8G7AUuV8ek6fkvfDsCfbNDP0dvRh0CrNqTbV7LfEEGDQPJQadBtfGVMWEq3QWWdufk6ZSNsjG2PQjp3ZcnOWWing6noonSInvi0/Ex+IzAreevPhe+CawpgP1/pMTMDo64G0sTCXIM+KdOnFWRfQKdJvQzV1+Bt8OokmrdtY2yhVX2a+qrykJfMq4Ml3VR4cVzTQVz+UoNne4vcKLoyS+gyKO6EHe+75Fdt0Mbe5bRIf/wjvrVmhbqBN97RD1vxrahvBOfOYzoosH9bq94uejSOQGkVM6sN/7HelL4t10t9F4gPdVzydEOx83Gv+uNxo7XyL/FtFl8z9ZAHF4bBsrEwAAASpJREFUOBGlkz9ugzAUxm1UCaSUZAMxcoPsXbpViEP0CDlEl14lAwsnQJkipEw9BIxQVWLgX9+HhPNMQCKJJcDmvffzZ/uz7PtePNteOCBN0w/btg+GYWyX4FJKUVXVKcuy7yAIflGvIEmS7H3fP3qet2uahrPn+m9t224ocEBQQSzL2juOsyvLcq5I+0e5wjTNd1IlSXGvIMiCgq7rtIK5AXIoF5tp0NPiNbS6rsfu3V9NCTZzjRLaD8E3/gbCg0uSpjkPQzhIg0DmmuUAwG2gQSCfz7C0nOlECjKezhoI4GQRdbIKQlb+yfP8z3XdVy51qga2p2shyJRnig2mUpAwDC9xHH8WRQErb6fFfAxAFEVfpHq4vbAtj48yFVwLXge4XGDMQ65563v/HjuaxUG9zK8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
```

...which creates a checkbox.

What I'm wondering is, what is it called when you represent an image as text like this?  I ask because I want to look for image editors that will do this for me (or see if my current editor has this type of export) and I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Data URI Scheme  -- see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: It's actually the encoded bytes of the image. You might see that with browser extensions that inject images onto the page...One that comes to mind is Lastpass...the little Lastpass icons that injects use this style of image (raw bytes vs image link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's encrypted in BASE64, you can do it [HERE](http://www.base64-image.de/)

Comment: Thank you!  I guess my answer was right in front of me the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the code ;) 
This is a Base64 encoded data-URI. 
Try it here: http://www.base64-image.de/